# Changing Text Field Value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know this question is asked many times but my problem is a little different.
and Second I newbie to use ajax..

Through Ajax i'm getting value from a Servlet. The value is returned and Jquery give me the correct alert of value but still the value in Textfield do not change.

The value in textfield should be changed when value in select is changed.

Select Code

```
<select id="category" name="itemCategory" id="itemCategory"     
onchange="populateBillId(this)">
    <option selected="selected">Customer</option>
    <option>Borrower</option> 
</select>
```

TextField

```
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Bill ID" id="billId" 
 name="billId" value="${BillId}" readonly/>
```

Jquery Code

```
function populateBillId(obj){
    var table;
    if(obj.value=='Borrower'){
        table="borrowerbills";
    }else if(obj.value=='Customer'){
        table="customerbills";
    }
    $.get('populateBillId', {
        tableName : table
    }, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        var id=response;
        $("#billId").val(id);
    });
}
```

I'm presenting Screen shot here.
[image]

Comment: Click the console tab to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Nope I checked So many time.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `$("#billId")` object to the console, to ensure that you're selecting the element?

Comment: Ok i will try this also

Comment: In Debugger value of $("#billId") is  billId = "" While it contain a value...   CB-0001

Comment: I do not know why it neither getting value nor assigning value....

Comment: @MrBearding  Thank You I just got it. there was another id with same name which was conflicting with it..

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan, you should never have two elements with the same ID on one page..